# Не отлавливаются контролы Qt5

Tags: qt, gui, юнит-тесты, qt5

Пишу скрипты для приложения на Qt на AutoIT - наткнулся на такую проблему - не могу использовать в скрипте контролы окна - просто не знаю как. Само окно использую через получение дескриптора окна через его заголовок.

Как использовать кнопки/текстбоксы и т.д.? Ни Spy++, ни прочие утилиты нужной информации не предоставляют (или я ошибаюсь?). Могу получить, например, в кнопке информацию о его номере, как дочернего элемента окна. При этом список дочерних элементов окна - пуст.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не знаю как работает AutoIT, но вот Qt-виджеты, за исключением верхних окон, не являются контролами Windows. Поэтому Spy их и не видит — их там просто нет. Qt приложение самостоятельно преобразует сырые сообщения Windows в те, что нужны виджетам. Поэтому, если AutoIT использует подход: «получи хэндл, а потом с ним что-то сделай», то это не сработает.

С другой стороны, Qt поддерживает [Accessibility](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/accessible.html), т.е. следующие технологии Microsoft могут быть использованы: [MSAA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971310.aspx) и [IAccessible2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/accessibility/iaccessible2). Поэтому, если какая-то программа для автоматизации, использует эти технологии, то её можно использовать с Qt.

Так же, хотя и не относится напрямую к вопросу, вместо Spy, для интроспекции приложения Qt можно использовать [GammaRay](http://www.kdab.com/gammaray/)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!